# Disable TLS 1.0 from Windows server

Tags: ssl, server, tls1.2, windows-server

How to disable TLS 1.0 from Windows server 2016? 
I tried modifying windows registry. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the reg settings below.

Hive       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key path              SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server
Value name        Enabled
Value type          REG_DWORD
Value data           0x0 (0)

Hive       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key path              SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server
Value name        DisabledByDefault
Value type          REG_DWORD
Value data           0x1 (1)

Hive       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key path              SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client
Value name        Enabled
Value type          REG_DWORD
Value data           0x0 (0)

Hive       HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Key path              SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client
Value name        DisabledByDefault
Value type          REG_DWORD
Value data           0x1 (1)